# How do I enter a 'null' value in a LineSeries?

Tags: livecharts

I have a 'line' of values where some information might be missing.

e.g.:

> Jan - 10, Feb - 20, Mar - 15, Apr - null, Jun - 45 ... etc

I would expect that in the chart the NULL value will simply appear 'empty' (missing) from the line.

e.g.

[image]

I have tried using `ChartValues<decimal?>` but the chart complains in the XAML that it `does not know how to plot Nullable`1`.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiveCharts uses `double.NaN` instead of `null` this is the example in the web site:

https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Missing%20Points

```
Series = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>
                {
                    4,
                    5,
                    7,
                    8,
                    double.NaN,
                    5,
                    2,
                    8,
                    double.NaN,
                    6,
                    2
                }
            }
        };
```

XAML

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}"></lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused as to why I can't use `decimal` in line chart.

Comment: you can plot any type, sadly this feature requires double.nan, an alternative is to cast your decimal points to double

Comment: Any idea how this works with `StepLine`? `Double.NaN` isn't allowed there.